# How to assign generic type of return value of api call to ref

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, typescript-generics, vue-script-setup

I have a component which is supposed to handle strongly typed API calls passed as prop. After the call, its return value is then stored into ref (and passed outside through the scoped slot). The problem is I can't figure out how to make ref understand the type of returned value.

This is what I've tried

Example of API call:

```
const fetchStuff = async (): Promise<boolean> => {
  // fetch and return the result here
}
```

The API handler component (simplified):

```
<template>
  <slot :result="result"></slot>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
  import { defineProps, ref } from 'vue'

  type ApiHandlerProps = {
    call: () => Promise<unknown>
  }

  const props = defineProps<ApiHandlerProps>()

  // HOW TO TYPE THIS WITH GENERICS? -> INFERING DOES NOT WORK!
  const result = ref<???>(undefined)

  const handleApiCall = async <T>(apiCall: () => Promise<T>) => {
    try {
      const response = await apiCall()

      result.value = response
    } catch (error) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  handleApiCall(props.call)
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<template>
  <api-handler :call="fetchStuff" v-slot={ result }>
    // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE RESULT
  </api-handler>
</template>
```

Struggled to find help with this kind of approach, so I ask here.

---

EDIT - 23-01-02

I tried to use composable as @leifmarcus suggested like this:

As composable / api-handler-utils.ts:

```
import { shallowRef } from 'vue'

export const handleApiCall = async <T>(apiCall: () => Promise<T>) => {
  const result = shallowRef<T | undefined>(undefined)

  try {
    const response = await apiCall()

    result.value = response
  } catch (error) {
    //...
  }

  return result
}
```

Note! Used shallowRef instead of ref to dodge another linting error.

Ended up having another error by trying to import function from ts file. Seems like there is a new error around every corner. At this point, working with Vue seems to take more time to figure out how to solve small edge cases / errors. After all, coming from React (which I hate) background, this is supposed to be a relatively easy thing to do. So I started to read Svelte's docs :D

Comment: Does `const result = ref<ApiHandlerProps>(undefined)` not work? Might have to do `const result = ref<ApiHandlerProps>(undefined as ApiHandlerProps)`.  Edit: reread question and misunderstood I think, you want to use `ref<T>(undefined)`, but outside `handleApiCall`'s scope?

Comment: Do I understand it correct, that you want to use the API handler for different kind of API Calls? Why don’t you make use of a composable? As far as I know you will not be able to have a generic type for component props which you would need here, right?

Comment: you might want to have a look into this article: https://logaretm.com/blog/generic-type-components-with-composition-api/. It describes how to work with generic types for props.

Comment: @RussDeneychuk, yes that is exactly what I'd want to do. However, I can't figure out how to pass T for the ref from handleApiCall function.

Comment: @LeifMarcus, thanks for the tip, I will look into that link you sent. Seems a bit complicated though. I thought it would be enough to use Promise<unknown> as a type of callback passed as a prop and then handle things as generics inside the component but no.

Comment: First of all stop `<T>` everywhere!!! You are not building any commercial library! When you make a Ref and you assign to it undefined, obvious is that it has to have condition to return undefined, so `ref<any | undefined>(udefined)`. You can change `any` to what ever interface you want.

Comment: `<T>` can be used exactly for this purpose. It has nothing to do with commercial libraries. Using `any` is a really bad style and in serious projects not allowed by linting rules. Also you will not have correct type checking for your results which makes Typescript somehow useless

Comment: Never use any! Actually, prevent it entirely! Also, never use assertions either (except if you really really have to do it for some odd reason). The idea is to lean on typescripts infering instead of dev taking the responsibility of types to be as intended. In this way errors get noticed.

Comment: Btw... I ended up changing the whole framework to Svelte and I'm really really glad I did it. Fortunately my app was so small/young that it wasn't too big of a deal. Have to say that I ENJOY doing frontend once again with it! Also, solved this exact problem with ease with it :)